# Program that continues loop after invalid input?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I am trying to create a program that asks the user for an exponent and then takes the exponent and does the operation (e^exponent). If the user inputs a value that is not a double, the program prints "Invalid input.", and continues asking for an exponent. However, I cannot get this code to work and when I type a non-double into the debugger it infinitely prints "Enter exponent: Invalid input".

```
importjava.util.Scanner;
class loops{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   double exponent;
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
   do {
     System.out.print("Enter exponent: ");
     if(s.hasNextDouble()){
        exponent = s.nextDouble();
        double result;
        result = Math.exp(exponent);
        String x;
        x = "Result = " + String.format("%.4f", result);
        System.out.print(x);
        System.out.print('\n');
        System.out.println();
     }
     else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input.");
     }
  }while (true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input caught by the scanner is not reset when you get to the *else* clause. Adding `s.next();` before printing « Invalid Input » should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I am also trying to get the program to break from the loop when the user types "quit". But when I try to change the while loop to while(!s.equals("quit")), the code will not run as intended.

Comment: Using `s.equals("quit")` you are comparing your Scanner object with the String "quit" which will always return false. For this behavior you want to check if the user input is "quit". You can store the returned value of the `s.next();` statement you added to your else clause and break the loop if this value is correct (ie. "quit"). If it is not correct just print "Invalid Input".